# Opening new Android project Error

Tags: eclipse-adt

I have installed ADT plugin for Eclipse Indigo, and I have not encountered any problems during installation. However once I tried to start a new android project through File > New > Android > Android project I got this error "Problem opening wizard. The selected wizard could not be started".

After checking out the details of this error I have the following error detail:

"The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectWizard.
Bad version number in .class file"

Comment: do you have android sdk installed?

Comment: Yes i have android sdk, on SDK Manager i have installed the necessary packages

Answer (score 1):

Check your java version. It also happened to me and I switched from Java 1.5 to Java 1.6 in /etc/alternatives (Ubuntu).